# Creating dynamic flask route

Tags: python, flask

I'm attempting to create a dynamic flask route. I want to create a parallel page for my route that internal users can see when they add 'vo/' before the URL. So essentially there are two different routes `/vo/feedbackform` and `/feedbackform`. I know I could just create two routes in the app, but I'm hoping I can optimize.

```
@app.route('/<x>feedbackform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedback_portal(x):
    if x == 'vo/':
        return render_template('feedback_vo.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
    elif x == '':
        return render_template('feedback.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
```

So far, this only works when the URL using the vo/ in the `x` part of the URL by my `elif` isn't working, and I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of @ilias-sp's answer, I was able to use this code:

```
@app.route('/feedbackform/', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={'x': None})
@app.route('/<x>/feedbackform/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedback_portal(x):
    if x=='vo':
        return render_template('feedback_vo.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
    elif x==None:
        return render_template('feedback.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported by Flask.

For your case that you have only 2 paths to support, you can add two decorators/routes to same function and then inspect the `request.path` to render the appropriate template:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/vo/feedbackform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/feedbackform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedback_portal():
    if request.path[0:4] == '/vo/':
        return render_template('feedback_vo.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
    else:
        return render_template('feedback.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
```

If you had multiple options to support instead of just `/vo/`, you could look into declaring the dynamic part as `path`:

```
@app.route('/<path:x>feedbackform', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

And add one more route to handle the static `/feedbackform`.

Comment: hmm, I can't get that block to work. what does the `request.path[0:4]` do?

Comment: its supposed to check if the URL starts with `/vo/`. did you include the `from flask import request` line?

Comment: I did, yes. I was able to get my previous code to work by adding the static route above the line similar to you

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your reasons for wanting to have a single handler but if the snippet you provided is all there is to it, I don't see much in common between the two routes to warrant a single handler especially if you are going to use if-else to handle each case differently.

I would rather have separate routes - it's clearer and less convoluted (IMHO).

```py
@app.route('/feedbackform/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedback_portal():
    return render_template('feedback.html', title='Inquiry Submission')

@app.route('/vo/feedbackform/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedback_portal_vo():
    return render_template('feedback_vo.html', title='Inquiry Submission')
```

Comment: what i'm trying to do is essentially have a mirror site with the `/vo`. I used a basic example route. With the consolidated route I posted as an answers I can have the defined function perform an action and only apply the `if` and `elif` statements to the rendering part